# displaying NaN/NaN when result was not found jQuery data tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have jQuery data tables function I get from another question on SO. Here is the function:

```
var oTable = $('#test').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ],
    "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
    "iDisplayLength": 1,
    "bInfo": true,
    "fnInfoCallback": function( oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre ) {
       perPage = iEnd - iStart + 1;
       totalRatio = iTotal/perPage;
       intTotalRatio = parseInt(totalRatio, 10);
       totalPages = totalRatio > intTotalRatio ? intTotalRatio + 1 : intTotalRatio;
       currentRatio = iStart/perPage;
       intCurrentRatio = parseInt(currentRatio, 10);
       currentPage = currentRatio > intCurrentRatio ? intCurrentRatio + 1 : intCurrentRatio;
       return ' ' + currentPage + ' / ' + totalPages + ' ';
    }
});
```

This function is to displaying page/totalpage on pagination. But when I do search on search box, with no record inside the table, the pagination displaying NaN/Nan.

How to keep this pagination still displaying page/totalpage number?

Comment: Some example or link to the original question would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
totalRatio = (iTotal/perPage !== iTotal/perPage) ? 0 : iTotal/perPage;
//..
currentRatio = (iStart/perPage !== iStart/perPage) ? 0 : iStart/perPage;
```

Comment: Hi @chiliNut, after insert ur code now its Nan/0? any clue?

Comment: `perPage = ((iEnd - iStart + 1 >0 ) ? (iEnd-iStart+1) : 1)`

Comment: np. just a note: my code is handling "divide by 0 errors," but its just a band-aid. im not sure what is causing those errors to begin with.